# Efficient Way to Fill QWidget With QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

I'm trying to make it so that a user can manually set the background of a `QWidget` with their own `QPixmap`, loaded from a file. My goal is to fill the `QWidget` with the `QPixmap`, scaled so that the entire `QWidget` is filled (i.e. some of the `QPixmap` may be cut off by the edges, as long as the entire `QWidget` is filled). So, I can't use a `QBrush` to paint the pixmap, since I don't want tiling.

Currently, I have 2 member pixmap objects: `m_backgroundPixmap`, and `m_scaledBackgroundPixmap`. On every `resizeEvent`, I take `m_backgroundPixmap`, scale it to the correct dimensions to fit the QWidget, and then save it as `m_scaledBackgroundPixmap`. In my `paintEvent`, I simple use `QPainter::drawPixmap` to draw the scaled pixmap.

Is there any other way to do this that is more efficient? I'd rather not have to resize the pixmap on every single `resizeEvent`, especially if the `resizeEvent` is being caused the window edges being stretched, which means it's going to be getting a lot of these events in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can load background image from a file with Qt Stylesheets.

```
myWidget->setObjectName("myWidget");
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
    tr("Open Image"), "/home", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));
myWidget->setStyleSheet("#myWidget {border-image: url("+fileName+")}");
```

Also, applying CSS styles to custom widgets inherited from QWidget requires reimplementing paintEvent() in that way

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```